# Angular. Why view of my component not changing after used his methods in to the child's component?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I add new person using <**add-person**> component, after response success from server I called the *addToList* method (see below) from <**persons**> component with new person-data from response. Ok, *addToList* method worked (concole.log), array of persons was changed, but view not rendered again in <**persons**> component. It is interesting that if I add new person inside <**persons**> component, that is addPerson method in  controller, view of component was rendered with new data.

Array of persons from the server i rendered using *ngFor.

**persons сomponent** - parent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'persons',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let person of persons">{{person.fullName}}</div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./persons.component.css']
})
export class PersonsComponent implements OnInit {

  persons;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.persons = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPersons();
  }

  getPersons() {
    // Get Data from the server using Resolve Service
    this.route.data.subscribe(persons => {
      this.persons = persons;
    });
  }

  addOnList(person) {
    this.persons.push(person);
  }

}
```

**add-person сomponent** - child

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { personService } from '../../../services/person/person.service';
import { personsComponent } from '../persons.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'add-person',
  templateUrl: './add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add.component.css'],
  providers: [personsComponent] 
})
export class AddPersonComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private personService: personService,
    private personsComponent: personsComponent
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  addPerson(form) {
    let person = form.value;

    this.personService.addPerson(person).subscribe(person => {
      this.personsComponent.addOnList(person);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: If you look in the console, do you see any errors? You cannot register a component as a service. So you can't do this: `providers: [personsComponent] `

Comment: DeborahK , there are not errors in console. Params are passed as expected

Comment: Possibly:
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
Let me know if this helps:
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html
https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had the right idea here with the service. If you want to share data between components, services is a good way to achieve it.

Ensure that your service exposes the persons array. It could also contain your addPerson method (which it looks like it does?)

The PersonsComponent should then have code that looks like this:

```
 get persons() {
    return this.personService.persons;
 }
```

This will ensure it is always getting the correct set of persons from the person service that is maintaining it.

Comment: If service will be contain addPerson method, after adding I should called getPersons again in <person> component? I don't understand) Look on my service https://plnkr.co/edit/DU111WcpPCkp8ZU4KOL7

Comment: This is a `getter`. The binding in your ngFor will automatically call this method.

Comment: Could you add your person component/template to your plunker?

Comment: This may not be exactly right ... I can't run it because its missing all of the bootstrap stuff ... but check out something like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/5pIRAeB84hLe777JPgzk?p=info